# what's the difference NULL, "", \0, empty in awk for variable‘ value

Tags: awk, null

Just like what the title said, I have no idea when the variable‘ value is **NULL** or **NUL** or **""** or **\0** or **empty**.

Can anyone explain them ?

thanks

Comment: especially explain **RS** variable, ^-^

Comment: RS variable `^-^` would be gawk-specific due to it being multi-char and it'd mean there are 1 or 2 records in your file depending if your file starts with `-^` or not. It's probably intended to be a nonsense setting of RS to a value that doesn't exiist in the file in an attempt to read the whole file as one record but the correct way to do that is `RS='^$'` and again it's gawk-specific.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no special `NULL` value in awk, nor is there a distinction between an empty or unset variable. If a variable has not been assigned a value, it will evaluate to the empty string `""` or `0`, depending on the context. For example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "a" b "c"}'
```

Here `b` is an unset variable. In a string context, it evaluates to `""`, producing the output `ac`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 1+a}'
```

`a` has not been set but is in a numeric context. In this case, it evaluates to `0`, producing the output `1`.

The null byte `\0` is a different matter entirely. You can print one just like any other escape sequence, such as a tab `\t` or newline `\n`. It's just harder to see one. To do so, you can use `cat -v`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "a\0c"}' | cat -v
a^@c
```

The `^@` in the output indicates the presence of a null byte.

You can also "see" the null byte using `xargs`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "a\0c"}' | xargs -0
a c
```

The `-0` option to `xargs` tells it that arguments will be separated by the null byte. As you can see, there are two arguments, `a` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Fenech
Thanks, the reason why I have such question is that I feel puzzled about the variable RS when reading the info of awk.

As info said:

> The empty string `""' (a string without any characters) has a special
>   meaning as the value of `RS'. It means that records are separated by
>   one or more blank lines and nothing else.

> BEGIN { RS = "\0" }  # whole file becomes one record?

And now, I konw it after reading your explanation！

Comment: `RS="\0"` can fail since some files can contain NUL chars. The only way to be guaranteed to read the whole record is using GNU awk and `RS='^$'` or in any awk you need to build up the record a line at a time `{rec=rec $0 RS} END{ do stuff with rec which now contains the whole file }`